# Type info in AST in Purescript

Tags: json, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, purescript

I'm working with Purescript AST. Dump-corefn gives out incomplete info about program: there's no info about types in `corefn.json`-file. 
What could you advise for getting full AST without type removing?
Thank you.

Example given [here](https://github.com/paf31/24-days-of-purescript-2016/blob/master/22.markdown).

Answer (score 4):

There is already [an issue for this in the compiler](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/2657). You would need to modify the compiler if you need type information. The only option right now is to fork the compiler if you want the full AST.